# Convert R code to Mathematica code of Poisson log-likelihood for the epidemic curve

Tags: differential-equations, distributions, parametric-functions, code-request, conversion

I want to  define a function that simulates the model for a given combination of parameters and calculates the Poisson log-likelihood for the epidemic curve of reported cases:

```
# INPUT
initial_state_values <- c(S = 762,  
                          I = 1,       
                          R = 0)

times <- seq(from = 0, to = 14, by = 0.1)

# SIR MODEL FUNCTION
sir_model <- function(time, state, parameters) {  
  
  with(as.list(c(state, parameters)), {
    
    N <- S+I+R
    
    lambda <- beta * I/N
    
    # The differential equations
    dS <- -lambda * S               
    dI <- lambda * S - gamma * I
    dR <- gamma * I             
    
    # Output
    return(list(c(dS, dI, dR))) 
  })
}
```

The translated Mathematica code

```
data = {{10, 19}, {17, 4}, {24, 5}, {32, 47}, {36, 38}, {38, 54}, {41,
     84}, {42, 55}, {47, 116}, {50, 102}, {52, 126}, {58, 153}, {59, 
    164}, {62, 172}, {63, 177}, {67, 142}, {68, 158}, {69, 151}, {75, 
    155}, {80, 125}, {81, 116}, {84, 101}, {87, 106}, {88, 116}, {94, 
    85}, {98, 59}, {102, 67}, {105, 57}, {114, 59}, {117, 24}, {118, 
    39}, {120, 31}, {128, 36}, {134, 8}, {140, 7}, {142, 3}, {147, 
    20}, {150, 7}, {155, 2}, {159, 25}, {163, 2}, {186, 10}, {191, 
    17}, {200, 7}};

dataTable = 
 TableForm[data, 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"Time", "Number Infected"}}]

(*total size of population*)
 n = 763;

times = data[[All, 1]];

(*Flu dataset*)
numberinfected = data[[All, 2]]

ClearAll[\[Beta], \[Gamma]]
sireqns = {s'[t] == -\[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n, 
   i'[t] == \[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n - \[Gamma]*i[t], 
   r'[t] == \[Gamma]*i[t]};

initialConditions = {s[0] == n, i[0] == 1, r[0] == 0};
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{sireqns, initialConditions}, {s, i, r}, {t, 
    0, times}, {\[Beta], \[Gamma]}];

(*Extract the infected values from the solution*)
infectedValues = i /. sol;
```

Now I am trying to translate the following code from R to Mathematica, so I could calculate the parameters. But I face difficulties how to do it.

My main difficulty how can I create this code that calculates the Poisson log-likelihood

```
 LL <- sum(dpois(x = dat$number_reported, lambda = 0.6 * output$I[output$time %in% dat$time], log = TRUE))
```

So then I will try to find through this method the parameters with greater accuracy than with the (sum-of-squares) method.

```
# DISTANCE FUNCTION

loglik_function <- function(parameters, dat) {   # takes as inputs the parameter values and dataset

   beta <- parameters[1]    # extract and save the first value in the "parameters" input argument as beta
   gamma <- parameters[2]   # extract and save the second value in the "parameters" input argument as gamma
    
   # Simulate the model with initial conditions and timesteps defined above, and parameter values from function call
   output <- as.data.frame(ode(y = initial_state_values, 
                               times = times, 
                               func = sir_model,
                               parms = c(beta = beta,       # ode() takes the values for beta and gamma extracted from
                                         gamma = gamma)))   # the "parameters" input argument of the loglik_function()
    
  
   LL <- sum(dpois(x = dat$number_reported, lambda = 0.6 * output$I[output$time %in% dat$time], log = TRUE))
    
   return(LL) 
}


# OPTIMISATION

optim(par = c(1.7, 0.1),           # starting values for beta and gamma - you should get the same result no matter 
                                   # which values you choose here
      fn = loglik_function,        # the distance function to optimise
      dat = reported_data,         # the dataset to fit to ("dat" argument is passed to the function specified in fn)
      control = list(fnscale=-1))  # tells optim() to look for the maximum number instead of the minimum (the default)
```

Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Since not all of use know R, we should post the ideas and the process of R instead of only post the code of R.

Comment: "But I face difficulties..." Specifying the difficulties would likely get you more and specific help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like we need to compute $\beta, \gamma$ using optimization with `NMinimize` in the form

```
data = {{10, 19}, {17, 4}, {24, 5}, {32, 47}, {36, 38}, {38, 54}, {41,
     84}, {42, 55}, {47, 116}, {50, 102}, {52, 126}, {58, 153}, {59, 
    164}, {62, 172}, {63, 177}, {67, 142}, {68, 158}, {69, 151}, {75, 
    155}, {80, 125}, {81, 116}, {84, 101}, {87, 106}, {88, 116}, {94, 
    85}, {98, 59}, {102, 67}, {105, 57}, {114, 59}, {117, 24}, {118, 
    39}, {120, 31}, {128, 36}, {134, 8}, {140, 7}, {142, 3}, {147, 
    20}, {150, 7}, {155, 2}, {159, 25}, {163, 2}, {186, 10}, {191, 
    17}, {200, 7}};

dataTable = 
  TableForm[data, 
   TableHeadings -> {None, {"Time", "Number Infected"}}];

(*total size of population*)
n = 763;

times = data[[All, 1]];

(*Flu dataset*)
numberinfected = data[[All, 2]];

ClearAll[\[Beta], \[Gamma]]
sireqns = {s'[t] == -\[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n, 
   i'[t] == \[Beta]*s[t]*i[t]/n - \[Gamma]*i[t], 
   r'[t] == \[Gamma]*i[t]};

initialConditions = {s[0] == n, i[0] == 1, r[0] == 0};
infVal = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[{sireqns, initialConditions}, 
   i[#] & /@ times, {t, 0, Last[times]}, {\[Beta], \[Gamma]}];



func[b_?NumericQ, g_?NumericQ] := Norm[infVal[b, g] - numberinfected];


sol1 = NMinimize[{func[b, g], {b > 0, g > 0}}, {b, g}]

(*Out[]= {84.3981, {b -> 0.180905, g -> 0.0748557}}*)
```

Visualization

```
Show[ListLinePlot[
  Transpose[{times, Evaluate[infVal[b, g] /. sol1[[2]]]}]], 
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. Is this way like the Poisson log-likelihood?

Comment: @AthanasiosParaskevopoulos If you need exactly the Poisson log-likelihood, then we have function `LogLikelihood[]` and `PoissonDistribution[\[Mu]]` to optimize parameters.